# Dropdown menu doesn't work on bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I tried to do a small dropdown menu with bootstrap but without success. This is the code:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Text</a>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
</ul>
```

Any idea why it doesn't work? Thanks.

Comment: do you have dropdown.js included? what do you see in console?

Comment: do you have errors in your dev tool? missing js? or any?

Comment: @tech_Love I do have regular js included. Not a dropdown jquery file because I dont know where to find one or if I need one. I just took it from http://getbootstrap.com/components/#nav-dropdowns and there is nothing there about adding dropdown.js file

Comment: In fact what I see its a regular menu, when I click it nothing happenes.

Comment: in your link http://getbootstrap.com/components/#nav-dropdowns, read here: .... and the dropdowns JavaScript plugin. check console too.

Comment: @WebO you need to include the JavaScript file that Bootstrap provides, of which, requires additional JavaScript files. Load those and everything should be fine. It's all there on the [**Get Started**](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/) page.

Comment: check this demo: https://www.bootply.com/nZaxpxfiXz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you load jQuery, bootstrap.js and bootstrap.css.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0z36747j/

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li>
    <a href="#">Text</a>
  </li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```